# Could annotation based and xml based configuration be used together in spring 2.5?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I've been working on a project where controllers have been written extending Controller classes. Could I configure and use the POJO based Controllers as well (using @Controller) in the same application?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks jamestastic and skaffman, its working all fine now :)

Below are the lines needed to to be addeded to the web configuration file to have them working together:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"                    ...line1
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd                        
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context                           ...line2
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">  ...line3



    <context:annotation-config/>   ...line4

    <context:component-scan base-package="myPackage"/>  ...line5

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>  ...line6

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>   ...line7

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/>  ...line8

</beans>
```

I was too lazy to not to add line 8 in my main application.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. You can mix them together as much as you choose. `DispatcherServlet` should recognise both old-style and new-style controllers together in the same app.

Comment: Many thanks skaffman :). Could you guide me to some reference where I could find how to configure my application so I could use both of them together?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  You'll need to include the [Spring JavaConfig](http://www.springsource.org/javaconfig) project library, as annotation configuration was not part of the 2.5 core.

[Here is an example](http://www.earldouglas.com/node/19) I wrote a while back comparing Google Guice with Spring.  Toward the bottom (look for @ImportXml), I show how you can combine Spring XML configuration with annotation configuration.  The configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@ImportXml(locations = "classpath:com/earldouglas/guicespringjc/spring/config.xml")
public class XmlSpringConfiguration {
}
```

See the [Spring Reference regarding combining XML and Annotation configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-combining).  This is from the documentation for Spring 3, but it should still apply (with perhaps minor changes in class names and paths from the old Spring JavaConfig project).

Comment: I think you may have mis-understood the question. He was referring to old-style Controllers and new-style annotated controllers, not `@Bean`-style config. Admittedly, the subject does suggest otherwise.

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood the question.  I'll leave my answer here in case anyone else happens to find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring >= 3.0 use [@ImportResource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html) annotation

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "classpath:/path/to/spring.xml", })
public class AppConfig {
}
```